# Proguard.cfg: (Can't process class [android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver$Stub.class] (64000))

Tags: java, android, ant, proguard

I'm having issues ofuscate a package since I add an external lib.

I already tried to make this:

```
-keep public class * extends android.content.pm.IPackageStatsObserver
-keep public class * implements android.content.pm.IPackageStatsObserver

-keepclassmembers class * {

public static android.content.pm.IPackageStatsObserver asInterface(android.os.IBinder);



}
```

and

```
-keep public class com.(namespace).corelib.** {*;}

-libraryjars libs/corelib.jar

-dontwarn com.(namespace).corelib.**
```

where (namespace) it's corelib domain.

But this compilation problem remains:

```
[proguard] Reading program jar 
[/mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/xxx/libs/corelib.jar]



BUILD FAILED

/home/jenkins/android-sdk-base/tools/ant/build.xml:875: Can't read 
[/mnt/data/jenkins/workspace/xxx/libs/corelib.jar] (Can't process class 
[android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver$Stub.class] (64000))
```

Comment: Try this     " -keep class android.content.pm.* { *; }"